# Find slash that are NOT followed by non word character

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for finding **slashes only** that are not followed by special characters.

For example, if the string is,

`/PErs/@loc/g/2`, then I regex should find slashes (`/`) that are before `P`, `g` and `2`. It should not return slash before `@` as `@` is a special character. 
I could write `\/\w` but it is returning me `/P`, `/g` and `/2`.

Comment: Is underscore `_` considered a special character?

Comment: No. Underscore is not considered as a special character.

Comment: What about a final slash ? Must it be captured or not?

Comment: Slash before 2 in /PErs/@loc/g/2 ? Yes, to be captured.

Comment: I meant the slash in `PErs/` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest one by using word boundary `\b`.

```
\/\b
```

`\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zH2xJ0/2)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [lookahead operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

#### Positive lookahead or *detect if something is present after (ahead)*

Try this regex instead:

```
\/(?=\w)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zH2xJ0/1)

We use here the positive lookahead operator `(?=)`. It will "detect" the position of a given expression but won't match the expression.

#### Negative lookahead or *detect if something is NOT present after (ahead)*

Alternatively, you can also use the negative look ahead operator `(?!)`.

```
\/(?![@])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zH2xJ0/3)

#### Negative lookahead with multiple special characters

This will match any `/` NOT followed by `@`. If you have more special characters, simply add them to the character class.

For example, if `#` and `%` were special characters, the regular expression above would become:

```
 \/(?![@#%])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zH2xJ0/4)

Comment: It works, but @ is not the only special character though (regarding second regex).

Comment: @sans481 Please check the last demo

Answer (score 1):

Matching slashes NOT followed by NON word character is not the same than followed by word character.

Have a try with:

```
/(?!\W)
```

This matches `slashes NOT followed by NON word character`

It matches the final slash in string: `PErs/`